# Copy/wrap vector<Class*> to vector<Class>

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, vector, std

Is there an std function to easily copy a vector of pointers to classes into a vector of classes or do I have to manually iterate over them?

Looking for the solution with the fastest/fewer lines of code :).

A solution that avoids copying without leaking memory is also welcomed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt there is such, below is one liner with for:

```
  std::vector<X*> vec1 = { new X, new X };
  std::vector<X> vec2;
  vec2.reserve(vec1.size());
  for (auto p : vec1) vec2.push_back(*p);
```

if you want to make sure no copies are made then you can use std::reference_wrapper<>:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<X>> vec2;
for (auto p : vec1) vec2.push_back(*p);
```

but then you have to make sure no element of vec2 is accessed after vec1 elements were deallocated.

Another aproach is to use unique_ptr like that:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> vec2;
for (auto p : vec1) vec2.emplace_back(p);
```

now you can ditch vec1, but then why not make vec1 of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>`?

Comment: And just for completeness: note that `vec2` now contains _copies_ of all objects pointed to in the first vector.

Comment: std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<X>> can be used to skip copies, but thats not what OP is asking for.

Comment: Can you give an example marcinj? I would be interested in this as well, but I imagine there's a chance of leaking memory if you avoid the copy - question has been modified to accept such answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it yourself. `std:transform` or `std::for_each` will help you:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional> 
using namespace std::placeholders;

class Myclass{};
Myclass deref(const Myclass *mc) { return *mc;}

void append(std::vector<Myclass> &v, Myclass *mc) {v.push_back(*mc);}

int main(){
    std::vector<Myclass*> foo;
    std::vector<Myclass> bar;
    /* foo is initialised somehow */
    /* bar is initialised somehow to hold the same amount of dummy elements */

    //solution with transform 
    std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), deref);

    bar={};
    // solution with for_each
    auto bound_append = std::bind(append, bar, _1);
    std::for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bound_append);
}
```

Compile wit `-std=c++11` (gcc).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat totally true, this can be anhanced :)

Comment: See molbdnilo's answer for lambda syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner with no manual iteration at all:

```
std::for_each(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), [&](auto x) { vec2.push_back(*x); });
```

(Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure about the reference-capturing lambda syntax.)

Comment: There is the lambda that I was missing!